# Alignment of divs in html

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. I am trying to align my divs. The first div has two inner divs with one on left and another on right like two tds of the same tr and then the subsequent three divs are all one below another. i.e. 4 below 3 below 2 below 1.

Fifth sixth seventh divs are to be display below first / second / third divs and are mutually exclusive, i can manage that in jquery. But I tried my best but could not get them to align properly.

I used block for all divs excluding the two inner divs in the first div which i used inline-block. Please find below the HTML markup and the image showing what i get with the styles.

**Image:**

[image]

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; display: inline;">
        First Left
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; display: inline;">
        First Right
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Second 
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Third
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Forth
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Fifth - Additional section either with First / Second / Third
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Sixth - Additional section either with First / Second / Third
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Sevent - Additional section either with First / Second / Third
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want to align them ? (align on the left,center or right)

Comment: Try giving a background colour to each div to see exactly where they are getting positioned. Also how do you want them to be aligned as asked by @Core972 ?

Comment: what is your problem and what you want can you explain properly

Comment: Thanks to everyone for providing me the answer. Though almost all are correct. I am voting my answer to the person who gave me the first correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your float:

```
<div style="clear:both;">
    <div>
        Second 
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/420x3sk7/1/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question then you want to align your first and second div side by side in first row and then after third fourth and fifth div will be there. if yes then following fiddle is ans for your question.

check fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/v8mcowqq/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="first">First Left</div>
    <div class="second">First Right</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Second</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Third</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Forth</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Fifth - Additional section either with First / Second / Third</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Sixth - Additional section either with First / Second / Third</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Sevent - Additional section either with First / Second / Third</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div {
    margin:0 0 20px;
    background:green
}
div:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
div.first {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
div.second {
    float:right;
    margin:0;
}
```

but I am not quit sure about your last two div positioning requirement. can you elaborate plz.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the float using `style="clear:both"` whenever your new row begins add this line before it `<div style="clear:both"></div>` you will get the desire output

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand **`float` behavior with `parent`**

See the `first left` and `first right` both div having float. So that `Parent` is consider nothing inside of div, **parent will independent**.

**For Fixed**

**1)** user  `clear:both;` for `second` div

**OR**

**2)** remove the `float:left` of `First Left`

```html
<div>
    <div style=" display: inline;">
        First Left
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; display: inline;">
        First Right
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Second 
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Third
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Forth
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Fifth - Additional section either with First / Second / Third
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Sixth - Additional section either with First / Second / Third
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        Sevent - Additional section either with First / Second / Third
    </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/qa255pw7/

Answer (score 0):

While floating elements are still a valid approach, there are more recebt techniques like `flex-box` that make it a bit more hassle-free. To align your first `div`s, for instance, use `justify-content:space-between`. If you are learning CSS, dive in on your own, there’s a [guide at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Also, you could use the CSS part of a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). Its grid system provides a wide variety of layouts that should meet your requirements half way.